# How do I implement Facebook login with SFAuthenticationSession or SFSafariViewController in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-oauth, react-native-fbsdk

What's the de-facto way to implement Facebook login with React Native? I'm looking for a way that Apple accepts (doesn't get rejected).

Apparently react-native-fbsdk doesn't use SFSafariViewController (it just opens a safari webview) and this isn't acceptable by Apple... they've rejected my app because of this.

My current code. Opens Safari webview.

```
    LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('browser')

    class FBLogin extends Component {
      handleFacebookLogin = async () => {
        try {
          const result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions([
            'public_profile',
            'email',
            'user_friends',
          ])
          if (result.isCancelled) {
            alert('Login cancelled')
          } else {
            const token = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
            this.props.login(token)
          }
        } catch (error) {
          alert(`login error: ${error}`)
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <LoginButton
            type={'primary'}
            block
            onPress={() => this.handleFacebookLogin()}
          >
            Login with Facebook
          </LoginButton>
        )
      }
    }
```

Rejected by Apple due to

> We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in or register for an account, which provides a poor user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "react-native-app-auth" library. It has implemented SFAuthenticationSession with SFSafariViewController (Apple way of authenticating users for iOS 11 & up). 
They have a pretty neat documentation: http://npm.taobao.org/package/react-native-app-auth